# Gremlin.net 3.3.1 ValueMap<Tkey, Tvalue>

Tags: .net, gremlin, janusgraph

I am building a social querying system using a graph database. I am using *janusgraph database* to achieve that. I am using .net as server side language, I found a library (**[Gremlin.net v3.3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gremlin.Net/3.3.1)**) that provide client for a gremlin server. In gremlin there exist a keyword valueMap to get key value of properties for a selected vertex. In gremlin.Net library there exist a similar function called **ValueMap<{Tkey, Tvalue>**, i can't found what the mean by **Tkey** and **Tvalue**. I there any documentation or example about gremlin.net library their documentation is very weak.

I put { in the ValueMap because when i put <> it will be omitted by stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like ValueMap is just a Dictionary. Whenever a type is prefixed by a "T" it means the type is generic. Which means, it can hold any native types (int, string, etc), and also user-defined classes. So, something like `ValueMap<int, string> = new ValueMap<int, string>()` would work. For holding something like vertex data, I'd say you probably want to use something like `ValueMap<int, float[]>`.

Comment: Thanks, Its work i used ValueMap<string, Object[]>() and its return values now. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on what Brandon said in his comment:

`ValueMap` is a step that returns a map (`Dictionary` in .NET) of property keys with their values:

```java
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],lang:[java]]
==>[name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[name:[peter],age:[35]]
```

(Taken from [the respective section of the TinkerPop docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step) which contains more information and examples.)

Now you need to tell Gremlin.Net the type of the Dictionary keys and its values so that it can deserialize the results received by your graph system (JanusGraph in this case). For the example above, the keys are always strings, but the values are either a collection of integers or of strings. So the query from above would look like this in Gremlin.Net:

```cs
g.V().ValueMap<string, IList<object>>().ToList()
```

(`ToList()` is necessary to actually iterate the traversal which is something that the Gremlin Console does automatically for you.)

Also note that [JanusGraph currently only supports TinkerPop 3.2.z](http://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/version-compat.html), so the recommended version of Gremlin.Net is 3.2.7.

Comment: Thank you that was a good explanation, I was using Gremlin.Net 3.3.1 but after your answer I replaced by 3.2.7 and some of problems gone but an exception occur when I request an Edge. I put this question with more explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239255/gremlin-net-system-invalidoperationexception-deserializer-for-janusgraphrela can you plz answer this question. and thank you again.