# Gremlin.Net System.InvalidOperationException: 'Deserializer for "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier" not found' exception

Tags: c#, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am new in janusgraph and tinkerpop. I am using  Gremlin.Net  3.2.7 to connect to janusgraph and all the request that return vertexes work fine for me but when I run any operation that return edges like *"g.V(61464).outE('father').toList()"* an exception in the library:

> **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Deserializer for
>   "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier" not found'**

the server didn't throw any exception, the serializes configuration are the default:

serializers:

```
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
 - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
```

but its working fine in the gremlin-client console. do you have any suggestion plz?

Comment: We are currently working on a .NET library for JanusGraph that extends Gremlin.Net to support JanusGraph specific types. The initial version is in review right now and if you or anyone else from the community is interested in improving JanusGraph .NET support, then you can help give it a review:
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet/pull/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like JanusGraph serializes edges in its own format as [`RelationIdentifiers`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/relations/RelationIdentifier.java) which aren't part of TinkerPop. So Gremlin.Net has no deserializer for this type. This means that you either have to implement your own GraphSON deserializer for this type or you change your Gremlin query to not return edges directly.

The TinkerPop docs contain an [example on how to write a deserializer for Gremlin.Net](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.6/reference/#_custom_serialization_2). (Note that you only have to implement an `IGraphSONDeserializer`, not `IGraphSONSerializer` as that's only used for writing.)

Or, if you instead want to change your Gremlin traversal, than you can for example just return the edge properties:

```
g.V(61464).OutE("father").ValueMap<object>().ToList();
```

BTW: It looks like you are sending your Gremlin traversals in the form of Gremlin-Groovy strings to the JanusGraph server. You can instead also write [Gremlin traversals directly in C# with Gremlin.Net](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.6/reference/#gremlin-DotNet). This makes it not only easier to write the traversal, but the execution is also more efficient on the server-side.

Comment: Its work for the edge thanks, but you are saying that I cant return edge and vertex in the same query, am I right?and if I want I must implement a serialize of it. I have some question about Gremlin.Net library but I will put them into a new question to make the reachable by other developer easily.

Comment: In general you can return edges and vertices in the same query. It's just a deserialization problem with edges coming from JanusGraph here. Apart from that, you can get a vertex and edge back in the same query like this in Gremlin: `g.V(1).as('v').outE().limit(1).as('e').select('v','e')`.
In GremlinBin: http://gremlinbin.com/bin/view/5a5a276f2422b

Comment: @janusgraph - am facing a similar issue.  Need your support help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263542/janusgraph-using-gremlin-query-in-net-core-3-0